# Setcookie в середине файла

Tags: php

Есть готовый пример.

```
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","login","password");

mysql_select_db ("info",$db);

   mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');;
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$name=$_GET['uid'];
if ($_REQUEST['hash']==md5('3965622'.$uid.'sdpfkjpowjif09w8ejf')) {

  //доверяем вконтактику, и далее полагаем, что пользователь действительно авторизован там
  //для учетных записей пользователей я решил выделить логины вида vk-********
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, random, password FROM tracker_users WHERE username = 'vk-$uid'");
  setcookie('uid','');
  setcookie('pass','');
  if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    //пользователь авторизован, просто пересоздадим куки
    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysql_query("UPDATE tracker_users SET name = '$name' WHERE username = 'vk-$uid' LIMIT 1");
    setcookie('pass',md5($user['random'].$user['password'].$user['random']));
    setcookie('uid',$user['id']);
  } else {
    //добавим запись в таблицу пользователей
    $random = mt_rand(100000,999999);
    $pwd = $uid . 'sdpfkjpowjif09w8ejf';
    $pid=md5(uniqid(rand(),true));
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracker_users 
      (username, name, password, random, id_level, email, style, language, flag, joined, lastconnect, pid, time_offset) VALUES 
      ('vk-$uid', '$name', '" . md5($pwd) . "', $random, 3, '', 5, 7, 0, NOW(), NOW(),'$pid', '0')");
    //вставили строчку, теперь создадим куки и перебросим на другую страницу
    setcookie('pass',md5($random.md5($pwd).$random));
    setcookie('uid',mysql_insert_id());
  }
  header("Location: /index.php");
}
```

Выходят такие ошибки?

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started in on line 30, 31, 33`
```

Comment: На какой строке ошибка появляется ? Номер строки.

Comment: что у вас в файлике db.php ? нет ли там случайно вывода сообщения о том, что соединение с базой установлено?

Comment: В строках 12, 13, 29 , 30, 32

Comment: 1. Пересохраните этот файл и db.php без BOM.  
2. Если в db.php есть вывод в браузер (echo, vardump), то помещайте данные в переменную, а после установки всех кук делайте вывод этой переменной.

Comment: Разобрался. Проблема была в том, что выскакивала ошибка. А вывод ошибки это тоже вывод.

Answer (score 1):

На счет не вначала документа - неверное утверждение.
setcookie насамом деле модифицирует заголовок документа.
соответственно setcookie не может выполниться тогда, когда все заголовки уже были отправлены и началось "тело документа". 
Т.е. любой web-документ состоит из набора заголовков (в начале докумнета, поэтому они так называются) и после того, как они выведены - начинается body

Пример №1:

```
<?php
setcookie('uid',1231);
echo '1';
?>
```

Этот код выполнится  - успешно.

Пример №2:

```
<?php
echo '1';
setcookie('uid',1231);
?>
```

В этом случае мы получим "headers already sent", т.к. в тело документа уже было отправлено "1", а значит более мы не можем никаких заголовков в документе изменять\добавлять, на что php нам и ругается.

В вашем случае что-то инициирует вывод (это может быть банальный пробел перед открывающим <?php или после закрывающего ?> или же некая функция хочет сказать про ошибку).

Есть возможность сделать так, чтобы и последовательность в примере 2 тоже не выдавала ошибку - например через output buffering, но это отдельная тема.

Comment: Даже интересно стало, что же помешает мне установить куки, не выполняя `session_start`? ) Смешали всё...

Comment: Да, это вообще из другой оперы, проглючило.

Answer (score 0):

`setcookie()` можно использовать строго до первого вывода на страницу, будь то HTML разметка или вывод PHP. Вы можете расположить перед установкой куков любой PHP код, но с условием, что он ничего не будет выводить на страницу.